# How to call a specific url at a specific hour with Cron?

Tags: php, cron, cron-task

I need a function to be triggered by the user when simply clicking on a button. This will set a job to be executed at a specified time (let's say 9am) and will eventually be repeated periodically. That would be handled by PHP

So i've though about using CronJobs alongside PHP. I've followed this [pretty good tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/managing-cron-jobs-with-php-2/) but I don't really know how to create the triggerred file (home/path/to/command/the_command.sh).

Could anyone advise me please ?

EDIT:
In fact What I am looking to do is to call a url, let's say www.google.com at 9am if the user pushed the button on some admin website. The admin part of the job would be handled by the system set up on the tut page I've linked. And I am wondering how should be the file that is called by this php script when the author says :

```
$crontab->append_cronjob('30 8 * * 6 home/path/to/command/the_command.sh >/dev/null 2>&1');
```

what should I put into the_command.sh to call a url ?

I don't want this url to be open in any kind of browser. This url will basically trigger a function on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are 3 posibilities

1) add line in crontab every time you have task. this one is BAD idea

2) add into crontab:

```
* * * * *  /usr/bin/php /path_to_your_script/script.php
```

and check in script current time/trigger all action for this time. Also bad, but better then 1

3) create deamon which will do your tasks. For example one which will start every hour and wait next hour for events schedulered, check every minute.

If you just need call url from bash, use following:

```
/usr/bin/curl http://www.google.com >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Thanks, I may have not been precise enough in my question, see the edit please :)

Comment: What is  >/dev/null 2>/dev/null for ? sorry, I'm very new to the cammand line

Comment: redirect output and error to /dev/null(ignore). otherwise crontab will email you output and/or error.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a PHP script you want to run at 9am, then your command in the crontab file should be something like:

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/mysite/script.php
```

where `/usr/bin/php` is the path to your PHP executable, and `/var/www/mysite/script.php` is the path to the PHP script you want to execute.  Run this command in a terminal first to make sure it works.

This will work with any command.  You are supposed to **replace** `home/path/to/command/the_command.sh` with the command you want to execute, **not** use that command literally.  Here is a command that will retrieve the page at http://www.google.com/:

```
/usr/bin/curl http://www.google.com/
```

Comment: Thanks, I may have not been precise enough in my question, see the edit please :)

Comment: Thanks man, I'll give a try. What will be the difference with wget that I found somewhere on the net for the same purpose ?

Comment: They are very similar.  By default, `wget` saves its output to a file, which you probably don't want.